# WordPress API REST error: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException:

Tags: android, json, wordpress, rest

Tengo un problema con el API de WordPress, quiero recuperar los POST que tengo en mi sitio que trabaja con WordPress, mediante mi explorador web ya logre recuperar la información que requiero mediante esta forma:

Uso este link = "https://www.sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?tags=54&?tags=55"

Los tag los uso para recuperar ciertos POST dependiendo lo que necesite o por nivel de usuario, mediante el explorador me devuelve la información de la siguiente forma:

```
[
  {
    "id": 3250,
    "date": "2019-03-01T09:19:24",
    "date_gmt": "2019-03-01T15:19:24",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http://sitioWeb.org.mx/?p=3250"
    },
    "modified": "2019-03-04T09:40:01",
    "modified_gmt": "2019-03-04T15:40:01",
    "slug": "respuesta-a-la-extension-del-convenio",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "link": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/respuesta-a-la-extension-del-convenio/",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "RESPUESTA A LA EXTENSIÓN DEL CONVENIO"
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": "documento.pdf EXT</a>\n",
      "protected": false
    },
    "excerpt": {
      "rendered": "",
      "protected": false
    },
    "author": 1,
    "featured_media": 0,
    "comment_status": "closed",
    "ping_status": "closed",
    "sticky": false,
    "template": "",
    "format": "standard",
    "meta": [],
    "categories": [
      39
    ],
    "tags": [
      54,
      55
    ],
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/3250"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
        }
      ],
      "about": [
        {
          "href": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post"
        }
      ],
      "author": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1"
        }
      ],
      "replies": [
        {
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=3250"
        }
      ],
      "version-history": [
        {
          "count": 1,
          "href": "https://seccion15.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/3250/revisions"
        }
      ],
      "predecessor-version": [
        {
          "id": 3252,
          "href": "https://seccion15.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/3250/revisions/3252"
        }
      ],
      "wp:attachment": [
        {
          "href": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=3250"
        }
      ],
      "wp:term": [
        {
          "taxonomy": "category",
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?post=3250"
        },
        {
          "taxonomy": "post_tag",
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "https://sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=3250"
        }
      ],
      "curies": [
        {
          "name": "wp",
          "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
          "templated": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Pero me devuelve este error:

> error: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException

Mi codigo donde recibo el JSON en android es este:

Aqui cargo mi WebService:

```
public void cargarWebService(String empresa, String categoria) {
        String url = "https://www.sitioWeb.org.mx/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?tags=54&?tags=55";
        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
        request.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }
```

Y estos son mis métodos onResponse y onError:

```
 @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Noticias news = null;
        //JSONArray json = response.optJSONArray("inicio");
        JSONArray json = response.optJSONArray("");

        try{
            for (int i=0; i<json.length(); i++){
                news = new Noticias();
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);

                news.setIdNoticia(jsonObject.optInt("id"));
                news.setTituloNoticia(jsonObject.optString("title"));
                news.setSubtituloNoticia(jsonObject.getString("link"));
                //news.setImagenNoticia(jsonObject.getString("imagenNoticia"));
                //news.setDescripcionNoticia(jsonObject.getString("descripcionNoticia"));
                noticias.add(news);
            }

            noticiasAdapter adapter = new noticiasAdapter(noticias);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            noticiasadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }catch (JSONException e){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error al cargar la informacion del servidor: "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No se pudo consultar los registros: "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("Error","No se pudo consultar el registro: "+error.toString());
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: El json generado por el sitio de https://seccion15.org.mx funciona bien; el json que tienes tiene un problema, le hace falta un "]" de cierre, tu problema debe estar en otro lado.

Comment: Si lo tiene pero no lo copie perdon, de echo, por ejemplo ese codigo donde se ve el json  es solo un resultado, la consulta me devuelve dos resultados iguales al que publique

Comment: Los datos que estas obteniendo vienen en un `JSONArray` pero lo estas recibiendo en **Android** como un `JSONObject`, creo que ese es el error.

Comment: Si de echo ya lo probe recuperarlo como un JSONArray ahora mi duda es como puedo usar esa informacion del JSONArray y mostrarla en una lista